# How to validate the json against a complex json schema which has multi level of references

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have a json schema as follows

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/arrays.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "description": "A representation of a person, company, organization, or place",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "fruits": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "vegetables": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/$defs/veggie" }
    }
  },
  "required" : ["fruits", "vegetables"],
  "$defs": {
    "veggie": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "veggieName", "veggieLike", "cropLocation"],
      "properties": {
        "veggieName": {
          "type": "string",
        },
        "veggieLike": {
          "type": "boolean",
        },
        "cropLocation" : {
          "type" : "object",
          "items" :{ "$ref" : "#/$defs/location"}
        }
      }
    },
    "location" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "required" : ["country", "state"],
      "properties" : {
        "country" : {
          "type": "string"
         },
         "state" : {
           "type": "string"
         }
       }
    }      
  }
}
```

When I give data as follows I am expecting error that cropLocation doesnt have state and country prperty. but it validates as success against that schema. How to define schema with multilevel complex objects.

```
  "fruits": [ "apple", "orange", "pear" ],
  "vegetables": [
    {
      "veggieName" : "carrot",
      "veggieLike": true,
      "cropLocation" : {}
    },
    {
      "veggieName": "broccoli",
      "veggieLike": false,
      "cropLocation" : {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried variuos ways to restrucutre the json schema, but is not working

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
          "items" :{ "$ref" : "#/$defs/location"}
```

"cropLocation" is an object, but `items` is a keyword that only applies to arrays. Simply remove the `items` keyword and make the `$ref` a sibling to `"type": "object"`.